# Patch base::library with wrapper in R

Tags: r, eval, wrapper, overriding, install.packages

Inside an R package, I'm trying to patch the `base::library()` function in R to specifically set the position of the loaded packages in the search path. I haveve defined several environments (all named `env:<something>`) and want to make sure that libraries are placed below these environments in the search path.

```
# wrap around library function.
library = function(..., pos = NULL) {
  print("NEW LIBRARY FUNCTION!")
  if (is.null(pos)) {
    pos <- grep("env:", search())
    pos <- if (length(pos) == 0) 2 else max(pos) + 1
  }
  base::library(..., pos=pos)
}
```

When I assign this function in the console, everything runs fine:

```
> library(stats)
[1] "NEW LIBRARY FUNCTION!"
> eval(parse(text = "library(stats)"))
[1] "NEW LIBRARY FUNCTION!"
> eval(parse(text = "library(stats)"), envir = globalenv())
[1] "NEW LIBRARY FUNCTION!"
```

When I define the above wrapper function inside my package, build it and load it in a new R Session, the following executes as expected:

```
> library(mypackage)
> mypackage:::library(stats)
[1] "NEW LIBRARY FUNCTION!"
```

But, when using `eval()` with the `envir` argument inside a function in `mypackage`, my new definition of `library()` is not retrieved:

```
# Functions defined in mypackage
testlibrary1 = function(...) {
  library(...)
}

testlibrary2 = function(code) {
  eval(parse(text = code))
}

testlibrary3 = function(code) {
  eval(parse(text = code), envir = globalenv())
}
```

In console, I get the following results:

```
> mypackage:::testlibrary1(stats)
[1] "NEW LIBRARY FUNCTION!"
> mypackage:::testlibrary2("library(stats)")
[1] "NEW LIBRARY FUNCTION!"
> mypackage:::testlibrary3("library(stats)")
>
```

The last function, `testlibrary3()`, did not use the new wrapper function.

I want all functions that call `library()` inside `mypackage` to use my wrapper function. Can somebody help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is the following, but as your question did not include a fully reproducible example (i.e., by uploading the package somewhere) it is difficult to tell.

As long as your `library` function is not exported from your package via the `NAMESPACE` it is not visible. Consequently, the only available `library` function to eval is `base::library()`.

Note that while your function resides in the namespace of the package the calling environment for `mypackage:::testlibraryX()` is still the global environment. There your `library` functions is not available. Try to export is and see if this helps.